# How to use both TapGestureRecognizers and Effects in Xamarin Forms at the same control at same time?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, long-press

I need to use TapGestureRecognizer and Long Press effect at Grid at the same time. I need to implement two different functionality one is at long press and one is at tapgesture. I implemented the tapgesture and longpress on grid and its working fine in ios. But in android only tapgesture is working. But if I remove tapgesture then long press effect start working.

How can I make it so that both can work at same time ?

Comment: Have you got any workaround it?